# gnuplot option 'set fit quiet' not recognised on Gnuplot Version 4.4, patchlevel 3

Tags: gnuplot

I have Gnuplot Version *4.4*, patchlevel *3* installed. According to synaptic, this is the latest version. However when I try to use the option 'set fit quiet', gnuplot does not recognise it, and says `unknown --- expected 'logfile' or [no]errorvariables`.

I would like to use this option as, if it works, all of the text produced to the screen when gnuplot fits some data would no longer go to the screen, and this should speed up the rate at which gnuplot makes the fit.

Does anyone else have this issue? Perhaps it is related to the patchlevel 3 I have installed??? How would I update the patchlevel if this is the case?

Comment: The current gnuplot version is 4.6 patchlevel 3. `set fit quiet` was introduced in 4.6.0. How you can update depends on your system.